# Removing one object from multiple sets

Tags: java, set

I have a main HashSet that contains all of a specific type of objects and multiple subsets that contain each a part of the Main HashSet.
My question is, whether or not objects dissappear from the subsets if they are removed from the Main HashSet?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Show us your code and your problem. Did you ever try your attempts?

Comment: Are your subsets views of/backed by the main set or are they separate sets that happen to contain the same objects?

Comment: The content of the subsets is determined by looping  through the Main HashSet and adding all objects that fullfil a certain criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Removing an object from a Set **remove it only from that Set**.

**Changing an object** present in a Set will change the object, so if the same object is also present in other Sets, **you can see the changes retrieving it from another Set**.

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove(java.lang.Object)):

> Removes the specified element from **this** set if it is present (optional operation).